# css3 width transition not working on image

Tags: jquery, css

I have added a class to my header with jQuery when scrolling down to style it differently. I have two logos of two different colours for each style. The original one is bigger than the one that loads when you scroll. I gave them both a diff width and targeted the class but the only one that the transition works on is the original one or #logo1.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
    $('#main-page').addClass('appear');
    $('#logo1').fadeOut(0);
    $('#logo2').show(0);
  } else  {
    $('#logo2').hide(0);
    $('#logo1').fadeIn(0);
    $('#main-page').removeClass('appear');
  }
});
```

```css
#main-page{
  background:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  transition: background 600ms ease-in-out;
}
 
#main-page .site-nav{
  right:2em;
}
 
#main-page .site-nav a{
  color:white;
}
 
#main-page a.login-nav{
  background:#2ad4dc;
  padding: 1em !important;
  font-size:0.8em;
  color:black;
}
 
#main-page a.login-nav:hover{
  background:#FFF !important;
  color:black !important;
}

#main-page a.vert:before,a.vert:after{
  background:#fff;
}

#main-page .liner:before,.liner:after{
  background:#fff;
}
 
#main-page .got{
  width:220px;
  transition:width 600ms ease-in;
}

.appear .got{
  width:200px !important;
  transition:width 600ms ease-in;
}

.appear{
  position:fixed !important;
  background:white !important;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:6;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px #333;
}

#logo2 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <a id="logo1" href="/">
        <img class="got" src="img/img1.png" alt="test" />
      </a>
      <a id="logo2" href="/">
        <img class="got" src="img/img2.png" alt="test" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="navi">
        <li>
          <span class="liner">
            <a class="vert" href="/">Home</a>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="liner">
            <a class="vert" href="https://medium.com/">Blog</a>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li class="log">
          <a class="login-nav" href="/meta">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>Try Now
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You say "transition" but do you mean the transition effect doesnt work e.g. a fade out or do you mean it doesn't get hidden/shown what so ever?

Comment: For the #main-page .got and .appear .got. The main-page .got width transitions work, but the .appear .got doesn't. I'm targeting the images

Comment: Would having only one img element and changing the src attribute a valid alternative?

Comment: I figured out a workaround I just used background-image for my logo-container and restyled everything to fit. It even works on IE :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are hiding/showing `#logo2` with the hide/show methods (that set the display property), and with `#logo2{ display:none }`.

An alternative could be having only one img element and changing the src attribute with the URL of the new image. Placing a hidden img element with the URL of the second image could be a good idea, so it's prefetched, before you show it.

Check the snippet below for the complete solution.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
    $("#logo img").attr("src", "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
    $("#logo").addClass("appear");
  } else {
    $("#logo img").attr("src", "http://via.placeholder.com/250x150");
    $("#logo").removeClass("appear");
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 600px;
}

#main-page {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: background 600ms ease-in-out;
}

#main-page .site-nav {
  right: 2em;
}

#main-page .site-nav a {
  color: white;
}

#main-page a.login-nav {
  background: #2ad4dc;
  padding: 1em !important;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: black;
}

#main-page a.login-nav:hover {
  background: #FFF !important;
  color: black !important;
}

#main-page a.vert:before,
a.vert:after {
  background: #fff;
}

#main-page .liner:before,
.liner:after {
  background: #fff;
}

#main-page .got {
  width: 220px;
  transition: width 600ms ease-in;
  background-color: blue;
}

.appear .got {
  width: 200px !important;
}

.appear {
  position: fixed !important;
  background: white !important;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 6;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px #333;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <a id="logo" href="/"><img class="got" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="test"><img class="hidden" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="test"></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="navi">
        <li><span class="liner"><a class="vert" href="/">Home</a></span></li>
        <li><span class="liner"><a class="vert" href="https://medium.com/">Blog</a></span></li>
        <li class="log"><a class="login-nav" href="/meta"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>Try Now</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your code snippet is doing exactly what mine does, when you scroll down the width transition doesn't work. Only when you scroll up can you see the desired effect.

Comment: Well, that's odd... I do see the transition when scrolling up and down

Comment: the width transition?

Comment: @atlas24 yes, exactly. Maybe I didn't understand the problem. However, I do see the width transition when scrolling up and down. I tested it with FF and Chrome.

Comment: I'm using chrome as well and it's not working. However tested it in firefox and it's working fine. This is very odd :/

Comment: @atlas24 my bad, thought I tried it in Chrome, but opened another FF window. I'll improve my answer to solve this Chrome specific issue.

Comment: Is it bad practice to move elements off screen like that? I found I can use visibility: hidden and acheive the same effect. I'm still unclear as to why it wasn't working my way. It was because I had the display set to none? However the first logo showed the transition just fine when it was set to display:none.

Comment: @atlas24 Is having only one img element and changing the src attribute an option?

Comment: Is you use visibility:hidden it will work, just consider that although it will be invisible, it will still be in the document flow, and users will be able to click the a element.

Comment: Yes that would prob be better actually. How would that work?